# How to convert \uXXXX unicode to UTF-8 using console tools in *nix

Tags: linux, json, unix, unicode, encoding

I use `curl` to get some URL response, it's JSON response and it contains unicode-escaped national characters like **`\u0144 (ń)`** and **`\u00f3 (ó)`**.

How can I convert them to **UTF-8** or any other encoding to save into file?

Comment: See also Unix & Linux: **[In bash, how can I convert a Unicode Codepoint \[0-9A-F\] into the printabale character?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12273)**

Comment: The best way - use jq.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I don't know which distribution you are using, but **uni2ascii** should be included.

```
$ sudo apt-get install uni2ascii
```

It only depend on libc6, so it's a lightweight solution (uni2ascii i386 4.18-2 is 55,0 kB on Ubuntu)!

Then to use it:

```
$ echo 'Character 1: \u0144, Character 2: \u00f3' | ascii2uni -a U -q
Character 1: ń, Character 2: ó
```

Comment: That allow to display it, but not to save/convert it... even with uni2ascii unicode.txt > newfile.txt ... iconv do it well

Comment: `echo 'Character 1: \u0144, Character 2: \u00f3' | ascii2uni -a U -q > newfile.txt` clearly works and saves the output into `newfile.txt`.

Answer (score 52):

Might be a bit ugly, but `echo -e` should do it:

```
echo -en "$(curl $URL)"
```

`-e` interprets escapes, `-n` suppresses the newline `echo` would normally add.

Note: The `\u` escape works in the bash builtin `echo`, but not `/usr/bin/echo`.

As pointed out in the comments, this is bash 4.2+, and 4.2.x have a bug handling 0x00ff/17 values (0x80-0xff).

Comment: I don't think `\u` is a supported escape sequence.

Comment: Is that zsh by any chance? In which case, `s/supported/generally supported/` :-)

Comment: @cbuckley it was bash (as I added to the post, I figured out it was the bash builtin), but zsh's echo works with `\u` too. `csh`'s does not, however.

Comment: Please provide me example how to convert such escapes as \u0144 with "-e" switch.

Comment: @KrzysztofWolny The example is already in my post, either store the URL you're trying to get into the `URL` variable, or just replace it manually. `$(command)` executes `command`, so `$(curl $URL)` fetches the page at `$URL`.

Comment: @andrej under what conditions? binary, bash builtin, zsh builtin? If you don't need it variable, `$'\u00ed'` works in bash and zsh.

Comment: @Kevin echo -e "\u0160ini\u010di Ho\u0161i - A\u017e sa skon\u010d\u00ed zima" should produce "Šiniči Hoši - Až sa skončí zima" and it have problem with last "í" within "skončí" word. Using echo from bash 4.2.24(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) - the builtin version on Fedora 17-64 which use utf-8 console.

Comment: Use of the `\u...` and `\U...` escapes in `bash` requires `v4.2+`. @andrej: `bash 4.2.x` versions have a _bug_ where values between 0x80 and 0xff (128 - 255) - i.e., in the extended ASCII range - are NOT correctly UTF8-encoded and instead just passed through, resulting in an invalid UTF8 char that some terminals render as `?`. `\u00ed` falls into that range. As of (at least) `4.3.11` this has been fixed.

Comment: Note that in the `bash` versions that support it, `echo`'s `-e`'s `\u` escape sequence uses a different encoding than JSON; characters outside the BMP *will not* be correctly decoded by this answer. (e.g., the JSON value `"\ud83d\udca3"`)

Comment: How to prevent converting \n? It breaks my json.

Comment: text="${text//\\n/\\\\n}"

Comment: @Kevin it works for GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1) (Fedora 26). It does not work for /usr/bin/echo which is echo (GNU coreutils) 8.27

Answer (score 38):

I found native2ascii from JDK as the best way to do it:

```
native2ascii -encoding UTF-8 -reverse src.txt dest.txt
```

Detailed description is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/native2ascii.html

**Update:**
No longer available since JDK9: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8074431

Answer (score 23):

Assuming the `\u` is always followed by exactly 4 hex digits:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

binmode(STDOUT, ':utf8');

while (<>) {
    s/\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/chr(hex($1))/eg;
    print;
}
```

The `binmode` puts standard output into UTF-8 mode.  The `s...` command replaces each occurrence of `\u` followed by 4 hex digits with the corresponding character.  The `e` suffix causes the replacement to be evaluated as an expression rather than treated as a string; the `g` says to replace all occurrences rather than just the first.

You can save the above to a file somewhere in your `$PATH` (don't forget the `chmod +x`).  It filters standard input (or one or more files named on the command line) to standard output.

Again, this assumes that the representation is always `\u` followed by exactly 4 hex digits. There are more Unicode characters than can be represented that way, but I'm assuming that `\u12345` would denote the Unicode character 0x1234 (ETHIOPIC SYLLABLE SEE) followed by the digit `5`.

In C syntax, a *universal-character-name* is either `\u` followed by exactly 4 hex digits, or `\U` followed by exactly 8 hexadecimal digits. I don't know whether your JSON responses use the same scheme. You should probably find out how (or whether) it encodes Unicode characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane (the first 2<sup>16</sup> characters).

Comment: nice solution!! I'll hack the reverse way from [this code](http://icompile.eladkarako.com/yet-another-javascript-unicode-encodedecode/) later..

Comment: Why the heck should I code anything to transform from one standard to another? The wheel was already invented...

Comment: It is not exactly 4 hex digits. As of today, there are more 5-hex-digit unicode characters than 4 hex digit unicode charcters, 83502 vs 56354 to be exact. New stuff added (think emoji) will likely to need the extended space too. Assuming 4 digit is like assuming computer software won't be used past 2033 and 4 bytes is enough for storing a unix timestamp.

Comment: @PeerGynt At least in C, the syntax for a *universal-character-name* is `\u hex-quad` or `\U hex-quad hex-quad`. So a `\u` will always be followed by exactly 4 hex digits. If you need more than 4, use `\U` and 8 digits. (I'm not sure how universal that syntax is.)

Comment: @PeerGynt: I've updated my answer (see the last 2 paragraphs).

Comment: I'm getting capitalized special chars.

Comment: @MichaelDouma If that's a problem, you'll need to go into more detail.

Comment: I don't know why it happened, but instead of café, I got cafÉ. the unicode was right. But I didn't use your example, rather I tried to use in a pipe perl -pe 's/\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/chr(hex($1))/eg;'

Comment: Fixed with perl -Mutf8 -CS

Answer (score 23):

now I have the best answer! Use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)

Windows:

```
type in.json | jq > out.json
```

Lunix:

```
cat in.json | jq > out.json
```

It's surely faster as any answer using perl/python. Without parameters it formats the json and converts \uXXXX to utf8. It can be used to do json queries too. Very nice tool!

Comment: Note that you may need to add a dot ".": `cat in.json | jq . > out.json`. The dot is the most simple filter, it'll will no filter anything, just return whole human readable json.

Comment: at least in Linux, the dot is optional when it's the only filter applied over the pipe. You do need the dot if you're dropping the useless cat and doing `jq '.' in.json > out.json` though

Answer (score 13):

Don't rely on regexes: JSON has some strange corner-cases with `\u` escapes and non-BMP code points. (specifically, JSON will encode one code-point using *two* `\u` escapes) If you assume 1 escape sequence translates to 1 code point, you're doomed on such text.

Using a full JSON parser from the language of your choice is considerably more robust:

```
$ echo '["foo bar \u0144\n"]' | python -c 'import json, sys; sys.stdout.write(json.load(sys.stdin)[0].encode("utf-8"))'
```

That's really just feeding the data to this short python script:

```
import json
import sys

data = json.load(sys.stdin)
data = data[0] # change this to find your string in the JSON
sys.stdout.write(data.encode('utf-8'))
```

From which you can save as `foo.py` and call as `curl ... | foo.py`

An example that will break most of the other attempts in this question is `"\ud83d\udca3"`:

```
% printf '"\\ud83d\\udca3"' | python2 -c 'import json, sys; sys.stdout.write(json.load(sys.stdin)[0].encode("utf-8"))'; echo

# echo will result in corrupt output:
% echo -e $(printf '"\\ud83d\\udca3"') 
"������"
# native2ascii won't even try (this is correct for its intended use case, however, just not ours):
% printf '"\\ud83d\\udca3"' | native2ascii -encoding utf-8 -reverse
"\ud83d\udca3"
```

Comment: Why the heck should I code anything to transform from one standard to another? The wheel was already invented...

Comment: It is curious that you're revisiting this after four years. This answer does not, as you imply, reinvent the wheel: in fact it uses Python's built-in JSON parser. Many of the other answers in this thread attempt to force a tool not intended for this purpose, and as a result, will emit erroneous output on some valid inputs. Consider the JSON-encoded value `"\ud83d\udca9"`; both the highest voted solution using `echo` and your `native2ascii` solution will not process this input.

Comment: I was notified about some activity on this question. Agreed, that some answers here sucks, Still, if I have to code even 1 line instead of using already existing tool I'd call it reinventing the wheel. Your solution is limited to JSON content, how would you translate non-JSON content? I got your point that your solution works for all code points, but in my case your solution it's exaggeration, however I like the idea of parsing more then 1 code-point chars. Current accepted answer works for your example as well (however it's not printed correctly on my terminal, but number of "?" is the same)

Comment: "Your solution is limited to JSON content, how would you translate non-JSON content?" Changing something as drastic as the underlying storage format is going to necessitate a change in the tooling used to parse that format. "however it's not printed correctly on my terminal, but number of "?" is the same" It's not that it's failing to print; the �s are present because the command used corrupts the data, and garbage is output.

Comment: this solved a longstanding issue in [telegram-bot-bash](https://github.com/topkecleon/telegram-bot-bash/issues/50#issuecomment-482785810) because all other solutions I found on stackoverflow and elsewhere did not work! l will add my echo - drop in replacement bash function as seperate answer

Answer (score 11):

use `/usr/bin/printf "\u0160ini\u010di Ho\u0161i - A\u017e sa skon\u010d\u00ed zima"` to get proper unicode-to-utf8 conversion.

Comment: A valid solution, given that the question is Linux-related; just a heads-up for users on other platforms: not every external `printf` executable supports this (e.g., OS X 10.9.2 doesn't).

Comment: FWIW i think `printf` is related to the current shell you are running, ie. it's considered one of those fancy  shell builtins.  And I'm running fish shell 2.7.1 on macOS 10.12.6 and the above `printf "\u965"` and friends  works well for me.  ✧*｡٩(ˊᗜˋ*)و✧*｡

Comment: @Chris `printf` is part of current shell for sure, but the `/usr/bin/printf` is provided by `coreutils`

Answer (score 5):

Use the `b` conversion specifier mandated by POSIX:

> An additional conversion specifier character, `b`, shall be supported as follows. The argument shall be taken to be a string that can contain backslash-escape sequences.
>   — http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html

```
expand_escape_sequences() {
  printf %b "$1"
}
```

Test:

```sh
s='\u0160ini\u010di Ho\u0161i - A\u017e sa skon\u010d\u00ed zima A percent sign % OK?'
expand_escape_sequences "$s"

# output: Šiniči Hoši - Až sa skončí zima A percent sign % OK?
```

NOTE: If you remove the `%b` format specifier, the percent sign will cause error like:

```
-bash: printf: `O': invalid format character
```

Tested successfully with both bash's builtin `printf` and `/usr/bin/printf` on my linux distribution (Fedora 29).

---

**UPDATE 2019-04-17**: My solution assumed unicode escapes like `\uxxxx` and `\Uxxxxxxxx`; the latter being required for unicode characters beyond the BMP. However, the OP's question involved a JSON stream. JSON's unicode escape sequences use UTF16, which require surrogate pairs beyond the BMP.

Consider unicode character  (['GRINNING FACE WITH SMILING EYES' (U+1F601)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f601)). The `\U` escape sequence for this character is: `\U0001F601`. You can print it using the POSIX mandated `%b` specifier like so:

```sh
printf %b '\U0001F601'
# Prints  as expected
```

However, in JSON the escape sequence for this character involves a UTF16 surrogate pair: `\uD83D\uDE01`

For manipulating JSON streams at the shell level, the `jq` tool is superb:

```sh
echo '["\uD83D\uDE01"]' | jq .
# Prints [""] as expected
```

Thus I now withdraw my answer from consideration and endorse Smit Johnth's answer of using `jq` as the best answer.

Comment: FWIW, however well it solved or didn't solve the OP's issue, printf "%b" (combined with xargs) was a pretty good solution to a similar problem I had with find over some filenames that had emoji in them.

Answer (score 4):

> **Preface:** None of the promoted answers to this question solved a [longstanding issue](https://github.com/topkecleon/telegram-bot-bash/issues/50#issuecomment-482785810) in telegram-bot-bash. Only the python solution from [Thanatos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795702/how-to-convert-uxxxx-unicode-to-utf-8-using-console-tools-in-nix?answertab=active#tab-top) worked!
>
> This is because JSON will **encode one code-point using two \u escapes**

---

*Here you'll find **two** drop in replacements for `echo -e` and `printf '%s'`*

**PURE** bash variant as a function. paste on the top of your script and use it to decode your JSON strings in bash:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#
# pure bash implementaion, done by KayM (@gnadelwartz)
# see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55666449/9381171
  JsonDecode() {
     local out="$1"
     local remain=""   
     local regexp='(.*)\\u[dD]([0-9a-fA-F]{3})\\u[dD]([0-9a-fA-F]{3})(.*)'
     while [[ "${out}" =~ $regexp ]] ; do
           # match 2 \udxxx hex values, calculate new U, then split and replace
           local W1="$(( ( 0xd${BASH_REMATCH[2]} & 0x3ff) <<10 ))"
           local W2="$(( 0xd${BASH_REMATCH[3]} & 0x3ff ))"
           U="$(( ( W1 | W2 ) + 0x10000 ))"
           remain="$(printf '\\U%8.8x' "${U}")${BASH_REMATCH[4]}${remain}"
           out="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
     done
     echo -e "${out}${remain}"
  }

# Some tests ===============
$ JsonDecode 'xxx \ud83d\udc25 xxxx' -> xxx  xxxx
$ JsonDecode '\ud83d\udc25' -> 
$ JsonDecode '\u00e4 \u00e0 \u00f6 \u00f4 \u00fc \u00fb \ud83d\ude03 \ud83d\ude1a \ud83d\ude01 \ud83d\ude02 \ud83d\udc7c \ud83d\ude49 \ud83d\udc4e \ud83d\ude45 \ud83d\udc5d \ud83d\udc28 \ud83d\udc25 \ud83d\udc33 \ud83c\udf0f \ud83c\udf89 \ud83d\udcfb \ud83d\udd0a \ud83d\udcec \u2615 \ud83c\udf51'
ä à ö ô ü û                  ☕ 

# decode 100x string with 25 JSON UTF-16 vaules
$ time for x in $(seq 1 100); do JsonDecode '\u00e4 \u00e0 \u00f6 \u00f4 \u00fc \u00fb \ud83d\ude03 \ud83d\ude1a \ud83d\ude01 \ud83d\ude02 \ud83d\udc7c \ud83d\ude49 \ud83d\udc4e \ud83d\ude45 \ud83d\udc5d \ud83d\udc28 \ud83d\udc25 \ud83d\udc33 \ud83c\udf0f \ud83c\udf89 \ud83d\udcfb \ud83d\udd0a \ud83d\udcec \u2615 \ud83c\udf51' >/dev/null ; done

real    0m2,195s
user    0m1,635s
sys     0m0,647s
```

**MIXED** solution with Phyton variant from Thanatos:

```sh
# usage: JsonDecode "your bash string containing \uXXXX extracted from JSON"
 JsonDecode() {
     # wrap string in "", replace " by \"
     printf '"%s\\n"' "${1//\"/\\\"}" |\
     python -c 'import json, sys; sys.stdout.write(json.load(sys.stdin).encode("utf-8"))'
 }
```

-

---

Testcase for the ones who advocate the other promoted soutions will work:

```sh
# test='  ❤️  ' from JSON
$ export test='\uD83D\uDE01 \uD83D\uDE18 \u2764\uFE0F \uD83D\uDE0A \uD83D\uDC4D'

$ printf '"%s\\n"' "${test}" | python -c 'import json, sys; sys.stdout.write(json.load(sys.stdin).encode("utf-8"))' >phyton.txt
$ echo -e "$test" >echo.txt

$ cat -v phyton.txt
M-pM-^_M-^XM-^A M-pM-^_M-^XM-^X M-bM-^]M-$M-oM-8M-^O M-pM-^_M-^XM-^J M-pM-^_M-^QM-^M

$ cat -v echo.txt
M-mM- M-=M-mM-8M-^A M-mM- M-=M-mM-8M-^X M-bM-^]M-$M-oM-8M-^O M-mM- M-=M-mM-8M-^J M-mM- M-=M-mM-1M-^M
```

As you can easily see the output is different. the other promoted solutions provide the same wrong output for JSON strings as `echo -e`:

```sh
$ ascii2uni -a U -q >uni2ascii.txt <<EOF
$test
EOF

$ cat -v uni2ascii.txt
M-mM- M-=M-mM-8M-^A M-mM- M-=M-mM-8M-^X M-bM-^]M-$M-oM-8M-^O M-mM- M-=M-mM-8M-^J M-mM- M-=M-mM-1M-^M

$ printf "$test\n" >printf.txt
$ cat -v printf.txt
M-mM- M-=M-mM-8M-^A M-mM- M-=M-mM-8M-^X M-bM-^]M-$M-oM-8M-^O M-mM- M-=M-mM-8M-^J M-mM- M-=M-mM-1M-^M

$ echo "$test" | iconv -f Unicode >iconf.txt                                                                                     

$ cat -v iconf.txt
M-gM-^UM-^\M-cM-!M-^DM-dM-^PM-3M-gM-^UM-^\M-dM-^UM-^DM-cM-^DM-0M-eM-0M- M-dM-^QM-5M-cM-^LM-8M-eM-1M-^DM-dM-^QM-5M-cM-^EM-^EM-bM-^@M-8M-gM-^UM-^\M-cM-^\M-2M-cM-^PM-6M-gM-^UM-^\M-dM-^UM-^FM-dM-^XM-0M-eM-0M- M-dM-^QM-5M-cM-^LM-8M-eM-1M-^DM-dM-^QM-5M-cM-^AM-^EM-bM-^AM-^AM-gM-^UM-^\M-cM-!M-^DM-dM-^PM-3M-gM-^UM-^\M-dM-^MM-^DM-dM-^PM-4r
```

Answer (score 0):

```
iconv -f Unicode fullOrders.csv > fullOrders-utf8.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on MacOS:

```
perl -Mutf8 -CS -pe 's/\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/chr(hex($1))/eg;'
```

if you are piping.