# Convert Unicode symbol to entity in HTML

Tags: html, xml, character-encoding, entity, entities

My website content is based on an XML which I am getting from an external partner.

The XML code contains Unicode characters (sample: Δ) and my problem is, that my (UTF-8 encoded) website is currently not displaying it correctly. Instead of Δ I am only getting a ?

Is there a chance to resolve this on my end (how?) or do I have to ask the external partner to send the XML again with Entities?

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Δ Test</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `'<td>Δ Test</td>'.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace').decode()` returns `'<td>&#916; Test</td>'` in Python.

Comment: Still not solved. If I have a Unicode Symbol in my source code (and the web browser is not recognizing it, instead just displaying a questionmark): how can I display it? Do I have to automatically endocde the whole body text?? (and Python is not an option here)

Answer (score 0):

You can use & an then the unicode number, should be '&#916';

Comment: Yes I know. But I only have the Unicode character available in the given code. How can I display the character without having to (manually) change the charactor to the unicode number?

Comment: You could just right a short Program in Python like string = 'disajfodj Δ adsod '
string.replace('Δ','&#916'), if that is an option

Comment: or use php funktion utf8_encode()

Comment: Or use Javaskript function encode_utf8( s ){
    return unescape( encodeURIComponent( s ) );
}( '\u4e0a\u6d77' )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576905/how-to-convert-javascript-unicode-notation-code-to-utf-8

Comment: But in every case I would have to identify the Symbol as an Unicode Character first. Don't see how this could happen "on the fly" ?

Comment: I mean you could just convert the whole text, the text should stay the same because UTF-8 is a smaller part of Unicode, if I recall that one correctly. Or at least you could try that, maybe it works XD

Comment: sry I wanted to save ASCII is a part of Unicode and UTF-8 is only used to convert non ASCII characters, so your text would not be touched only the special Unicode symbols