# Curl replacing \u in response to \\u in c++

Tags: c++, libcurl

I am sending a request using libcurl in windows and the response I get has some universal characters in them that start with `\u`. Libcurl is not recognizing this universal character and as a result, it escapes the \ turning the universal character to `\\u`.
Is there any way to fix this? I have tried using `str.replace` but it can not replace escaped sequences
the code I used to implent this was

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cpr/cpr.h>

int main()
{
    auto r = cpr::Get(cpr::Url{"http://prayer.osamaanees.repl.co/api"});
    std::string data = r.text;
    std::cout << data << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code uses the [cpr](https://whoshuu.github.io/cpr/) library which is a wrapper for curl.
It **prints out** the following:

```
{
"times":{"Fajr":"04:58 AM","Sunrise":"06:16 AM","Dhuhr":"12:30 PM","Asr":"04:58 PM","Maghrib":"06:43 PM","Isha":"08:00 PM"},
"date":"Tuesday, 20 Mu\u1e25arram 1442AH"
}
```

Notice the word `Mu\u1e25arram`, it should have been **Muḥarram** but since curl escaped the \ before u it prints out as `\u1e25`

Comment: How did you check this extra escaping? In a debugger? Because debuggers tend to C-style representations of data (they also turn a 0x0D byte into `\r`, for example)

Comment: yes i used a debugger @Botje

Comment: If you print the string with `cout << data` there will be no double backslash. You were just confusing the debugger's representation for the actual memory contents.

Comment: I know it is doing this as I cant see the universal character when i use std::cout. it is showing as \u1e25 which should not be the case.

Comment: Try looking at https://groups.google.com/g/spray-user/c/4XCwzVeNyB0?pli=1 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795702/how-to-convert-uxxxx-unicode-to-utf-8-using-console-tools-in-nix They may give you an idea of how to deal with unicode in curl, although I think they are specific to unix-like systems.

Comment: @StevenW.Klassen those answers are specific to unix systems, in fact the same code works flawlessly in linux, the problem only arises when trying to compile in windows

Comment: @OsamaAnees I am pretty sure that escaping the \ after you received the data won't help. It's more a problem about the encoding the server uses to send the data. I don't know how to check for single Unicode characters in the string and replace them with something printable from the correct codepage. Maybe anyone else does here. Ty, for editing BTW.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ hopefully this has been bugging me for days lol

Comment: @OsamaAnees Note that editing your question always bumps it up at the home and [active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b?tab=Active) page. This will help you to get more attention again. But don't abuse that to edit repeatedly please.

Comment: Thankyou I will keep that in mind! @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: How are you so sure this is curl's doing? Ehat are you comparing against? Are you sure this isn't what the server returns? Representing non-ascii characters as a unicode escape `\uXXXX` is part of the JSON spec. And `cout` will not interpret json escape code by itself, it just prints what is in the string.

Comment: @OsamaAnees Maybe this helps what you need for replacement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015571/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-c

Comment: @Botje I never said I am sure... However I compiled the same code in linux using gcc and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your analysis is wrong.  Libcurl is not escaping anything.  Load the URL in a web browser of your choosing and look at the *raw data* that is actually being sent.  For example, this is what I see in Firefox:

[image: raw data]

The server really is sending `Mu\u1e25arram`, not `Muḥarram` like you are expecting.  And this is *perfectly fine*, because the server is sending back JSON data, and JSON is allowed to escape Unicode characters like this.  Read the [JSON spec](https://www.json.org), particularly Section 9 on how Unicode codepoints may be encoded using hexidecimal escape sequences (which is optional in JSON, but still allowed).  `\u1e25` is simply the JSON hex-escaped form of `ḥ`.

You are merely printing out the JSON content *as-is*, exactly as the server sent it.  You are not actually parsing it at all.  If you were to use an actual JSON parser, `Mu\u1e25arram` would be decoded to `Muḥarram` for you.  For example, here is how Firefox parses the JSON:

[image: parsed data]

It is not libcurl's job to decode JSON data.  Its job is merely to give you the data that the server sends.  It is your job to interpret the data afterwards as needed.

Comment: My analysis may have been wrong. I was using this [json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) parser. It parsed \u characters correctly in linux but showed weird characters in windows. At first I thought it may be because of libcurl but now I guess this might be due to how these os use strings differently?

Comment: @OsamaAnees I would expect any decent JSON parser to handle data the same way regardless of the OS used.  Without seeing your actual parsing code, I would assume the problem is likely elsewhere. *Outputting* the data maybe be different depending on OS (ie, needing UTF-8 strings vs UTF-16 strings, etc), but *parsing* shouldn't be.

Comment: Thank you so much! you made me realize what the actual problem was. _Outputting_. I changed the console output format and it worked by adding just 4 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank Remy for pointing out how wrong I was in thinking curl or the JSON parser was the problem when in reality I needed to convert my console to UTF-8 mode.
It was after I fixed my **Codepage** I was able to get the output I wanted.
For future reference, I am adding the code that fixed my problem:

We need to include **Windows.h**

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
```

Then at the start of our code:

```cpp
UINT oldcp = GetConsoleOutputCP();
SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
```

After this we need to reset the console back to the original codepage with:

```cpp
SetConsoleOutputCP(oldcp);
```

Comment: The Windows console does not handle UTF-8 very well, even with the code shown (there are *numerous* questions on StackOverflow on this topic!). It would be better to let the JSON parser decode the JSON to UTF-16 strings instead, and then write those UTF-16 strings to the console using Unicode APIs, rather than writing out UTF-8.